# How can I distribute values between several months in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the following dataframe:

```
    start_date delta   
    2018-06-30  2    
    2018-06-30  2    
    2018-06-30  2    
    2018-06-30  2    
    2018-06-30  4    
    2018-07-31  4    
    2018-07-31  2    
    2018-07-31  6
```

And I would get a dataframe like this:

```
start-date delta
2018-06-30   1
2018-07-31   1

2016-06-30   1
2016-07-31   1
 ...
# (there was 2018-06-30 with delta = 4)
2018-06-30   1
2018-07-31   1
2018-08-30   1
2018-09-30   1
 and so on...
```

I don't need spaces, it's just for visiualizing.
So I need to expand every month on delta. In the output each value of delta column must be equal to 1.
 How can I do it?

Comment: Your question is how to filter a DataFrame by the delta value?

Comment: No, I need to create a new dataframe where number of each date increases by delta( delta is column with numbers of months)

Comment: For instanse, the last date must be expanded on 6 months

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly each value in the 'delta' column is the number of months starting from the 'start_date'. In the results the 'delta' column has to contain only ones, so it is not really important and can be added later. Here is what I came up with considering that the values in the 'start_date' column are of the datetime64 type:

```
np.hstack((df.apply(lambda row: pd.date_range(row['start_date'], periods=row['delta'], freq='m'), axis=1).values))
```

This code transforms the dataframe from the question:

```
  start_date  delta
0 2018-06-30      2
1 2018-06-30      2
2 2018-06-30      2
3 2018-06-30      2
4 2018-06-30      4
5 2018-07-31      4
6 2018-07-31      2
7 2018-07-31      6
```

into a 1D array of dates:

```
array(['2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-07-31T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-07-31T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-07-31T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-07-31T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-07-31T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2018-08-31T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-09-30T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2018-07-31T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-08-31T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2018-09-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-10-31T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2018-07-31T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-08-31T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2018-07-31T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-08-31T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2018-09-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-10-31T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2018-11-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-12-31T00:00:00.000000000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

which can be used to create a new dataframe, ie.:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['start_date'] = np.hstack((df.apply(lambda row: pd.date_range(row['start_date'], periods=row['delta'], freq='m'), axis=1).values))
df2['delta'] = 1
```